# How can the following "funny identity" be generalised?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

When [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8814/funny-identities) for a "funny identity", Andrey Rekalo answered the following:

$$\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k\right)^2=\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk^3 .$$

Not only do I think it's funny, I also think it's very interesting. Therefore, I would like to know whether or not there are generalizations of this identity.

1. First of all, I am interested in higher powers higher than $2$. So if we consider $$\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k\right)^n  $$ for $n>2$, are there always ways turn this expression into other series without a raising them to some power? Only raising the individual terms to some power/factorial/function in general?
2. Second of all, I was wondering if similar identities exist for $$\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^m\right)^n  $$ for $m>1$ and $n>0$.

I guess the multinomial [theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) could be used, but I'm not entirely sure how to create such nice identities akin to the one mentioned by Andrey Rekalo.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/549823/generalizing-the-sum-of-consecutive-cubes-sum-k-1n-k3-big-sum-k-1n

Comment: @ALGEAN ah thanks!

Comment: The answer to point $(2)$ is NO, and [this question has been asked before](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61798/generalisation-of-the-identity-sum-limits-k-1n-k3-bigg-sum-limits-k).