# It is possible to get a closed-form for $1+2^i+3^i+\cdots (N-1)^i$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, summation

Let $i=\sqrt{-1}$ the complex imaginary unit, taking $$arg(2)=0$$ for the definition of the summand $2^i$ in $$1^i+2^i+3^i+\cdots (N-1)^i,$$
as $$2^i=\cos\log 2+ i\sin\log 2,$$

see [1].

> **Question.** It is possible to get a closed-form (or the best approximation possible), for an integer $N\geq 1$ 
>   $$1+2^i+3^i+\cdots (N-1)^i,$$
>   where the summands are defined in the same way, taking **principal branches of complex argument and complex exponentiation**?

*Thanks in advance*, my goal is start to refresh some easy facts in complex variable, please tell me if there are mistakes in the use of previous  definitions.

**References:**

[1] MathWorld, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexExponentiation.html http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexArgument.html

Comment: Try http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533772/a-formula-for-the-power-sums-1n2n-dotsc-kn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is a closed form, notice:

$$1^i+2^i+3^i+\dots+(n-1)^i=\sum_{k=2}^{n}\left(k-1\right)^i=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k^i=\text{H}_{n-1}^{(-i)}=\zeta(-i)-\zeta(-i,n)$$

Where $\zeta(s,a)$ is the Hurwitz zeta function, $\zeta(s)$ is the Riemann zeta function and

$\text{H}_{n}^{(r)}$ is the generalized harmoic number.

---

EDIT:

$$\zeta(-i)=\lim_{s\to0}\left[\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k^{i-s}\right]\approx 0.0033+0.4182i$$

Comment: Yesterday too another user wrote this answer, I assume that was right, but can you explain for example what is $\zeta(-i)$? Then you give more useful facts to me and other users.

Comment: Very thanks much for previous detail @JanEerlaand

Comment: @JuanLópezGonzález You're more than welcome buddy!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you make the assumption $$1^i=1$$When this is not true.$$1^i=e^{\pm2\pi n},n=0,1,2,3,\ldots$$

More generally, I will solve$$1^x+2^x+3^x+4^x+5^x\ldots=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^x$$This has solution obtainable via permutation:$$\sum_{n=2}^{m}n^x+n=\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}n^x+n^m$$$$\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}(n+1)^x+n=\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}n^x+n^m$$Apply Binomial thereom:$$(n+1)^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n^{x-n}1^nx!}{(x-n)!n!}$$$$\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}\sum_{i=n}^{\infty}\frac{n^{x-n}1^nx!}{(x-n)!n!}+n=\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}n^x+n^m$$

And now, to be honest with you, I can't proceed from here.

Or perhaps I took it from the wrong method of solving.

Comment: Very thanks much @SimpleArt , I've read your answer, with respect $1^i$ thanks for clarify my doubt,

Comment: OP explicitly states they use principal branches, so $1^i=1$ does hold.